# Getting element of JSON object when key isn't the same [Android]

Tags: android, json, key

I want to learn a bit more about android and wanted to create an app that will track the price of cryptocurrencies. I choosed this API: https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/#introduction

My problem is the following: When I want to get the list of all the coin the JSON response looks like this:

```
{
  "Response": "Success",
  "Message": "Coin list succesfully returned!",
  "BaseImageUrl": "https://www.cryptocompare.com",
  "BaseLinkUrl": "https://www.cryptocompare.com",
  "Data": {
    "42": {
      "Id": "4321",
      "Url": "/coins/42/overview",
      "ImageUrl": "/media/19984/42.png",
      "Name": "42",
      "CoinName": "42 Coin",
      "FullName": "42 Coin (42)",
      "Algorithm": "Scrypt",
      "ProofType": "PoW",
      "FullyPremined": "0",
      "TotalCoinSupply": "42",
      "PreMinedValue": "N/A",
      "TotalCoinsFreeFloat": "N/A",
      "SortOrder": "34"
    },
    "365": {
      "Id": "33639",
      "Url": "/coins/365/overview",
      "ImageUrl": "/media/352070/365.png",
      "Name": "365",
      "CoinName": "365Coin",
      "FullName": "365Coin (365)",
      "Algorithm": "X11",
      "ProofType": "PoW/PoS",
      "FullyPremined": "0",
      "TotalCoinSupply": "2300000000",
      "PreMinedValue": "299000000",
      "TotalCoinsFreeFloat": "N/A",
      "SortOrder": "916"
    },
```

(here is the URL I use (https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/)

I want to keep all the informations about the coin (everything from "Data") but the key isn't the same.

How can I get those informations to create my differents coins?

Thank's in advance

Comment: You can just loop through the JSONArray object

Comment: Yep but this is not an array, this is an object. That's my problem

Comment: You can use Iterator to loop through keys: Iterator<String> keysIterator = my_json_object.keys(); 
while (keysIterator.hasNext())

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Parse Json with array with different object types (Gson or Jackson or etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639018/java-parse-json-with-array-with-different-object-types-gson-or-jackson-or-etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSONObject#names()` to get all the keys as `JSONArray` and loop the `JSONArray`.

```
    JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("Data");

    JSONArray array = data.names(); // contains all the keys inside Data

    // now loop the array

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++ ) {
        String key = array.getString(i); // 42 or 365 for your example code
        JSONObject obj = data.getJSONObject(key); //  contains the JSONObject of the key 42 or 365
    }
```

Another way is to use `JSONObject#keys()` but that uses `Iterator` and `hasNext()` for iteration which is less performance efficient than the above normal `for` loop approach in Android.

Comment: Awsome man! Thanks you very much, I looked for all the function after the . but never thought of "name"

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is fine. I would like to show the way of parsing using [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) from your JSON. Here's how it can be parsed using Gson.

You need to have two classes.

Here's your `APIResponse.java`

```
public class APIResponse {
    public String Response;
    public String Message;
    public String BaseImageUrl;
    public String BaseLinkUrl;
    public HashMap<String, DataObject> Data;
}
```

And the `DataResponse` class should look like

```
public class DataObject {
    public String Id;
    public String Url;
    public String ImageUrl;
    public String Name;
    public String CoinName;
    public String FullName;
    public String Algorithm;
    public String ProofType;
    public String FullyPremined;
    public String TotalCoinSupply;
    public String PreMinedValue;
    public String TotalCoinsFreeFloat;
    public String SortOrder;
}
```

Now its pretty easy.

```
Type type = new TypeToken<APIResponse>(){}.getType();
APIResponse response = new Gson().fromJson(yourJsonString, type);
```

Now iterate the `HashMap` for getting the keys and corresponding values.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all the keys and iterate as below

```
try {
        JSONObject dataObj = obj.getJSONObject("Data");    //obj is the parent json object.
        Iterator<?> keys = dataObj.keys();

        while(keys.hasNext()) {
            JSONObject coinObj = dataObj.getJSONObject(keys.next().toString());   
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```