# Retrofit 2 Json Response Body

Tags: json, kotlin, retrofit

I have a JSON like below:

```
{"product" : {
            "product-s" : {
                "count" : 1,
                "name" : "Product S"
            },
            "product-xs" : {
                "count" : 1,
                "name" : "Product XS"
            },
            "product-m" : {
                "count" : 1,
                "name" : "Product M"
            }  
}
```

I can get a Response body using Retrofit call and can get the element product
by

```
val inventoryItem = response.body()!!
val itemList = inventoryItem.get("product")
```

how can I get the other elements from jsonElement "product"?

i.e., I want to get the count and name of the product "product-s"

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom deserializer for product items.

This response will help you.
[Custom Deserializer Example - Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45640511/6176842)

Other way you can create a pojo class that wrapper json for each product items but I don't suggest this way.