# How to decode dynamic key from JSON using retrofit - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I'm stuck decoding a dynamic value from a json file with kotlin

```
{
    "values": {
        "16694990259825982nLJ": {
            "id": "16694990259825982nLJ",
            "createdAt": "2022-11-26T21:43:45.982Z",
            "name": "Some Text",
            "owner": "xxxx@xxxx.xx",
            "category": "Some Text",
            "description": "Some Text.",
            "template_id": "Some Text",
            "last_update": "2022-11-27T00:11:51.863Z",
            "users": [
                "xxxx@xxxx.xx"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my data class :

```
@Serializable
data class WorkflowsTest(
    @field:SerializedName("values")
    val values: Map<String, Id>
)

@Serializable
data class Id(

    @field:SerializedName("owner")
    val owner: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("createdAt")
    val createdAt: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("last_update")
    val lastUpdate: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("name")
    val name: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("description")
    val description: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("template_id")
    val templateId: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("id")
    val id: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("category")
    val category: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("users")
    val users: List<String?>? = null
)
```

This is my ApiResponse data class when fetching Data from GET HTTP URL :

```
@Serializable
data class ApiResponse(
    @Transient
    val success: Boolean? = null,
    val message: String? = null,
    val values: WorkflowsTest? = null,
    val status: Int,
    @Transient
    val error: Exception? = null
)
```

And this is my retrofit provider network from network module

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}
```

Logs that I get when I get the response back :
`ApiResponse(success=null, message=null, **values=WorkflowsTest(values=null)**, status=1, error=null)`

as you can see values are null no matter what I do, status = 1 means the request is 200 OK, success, error and message are transient and manipulated for snackbar messages.

Test on main function :

```
fun main() {
    val jsonString = """
        {
    "values": {
        "16694990259825982nLJ": {
            "id": "16694990259825982nLJ",
            "createdAt": "2022-11-26T21:43:45.982Z",
            "name": "Some Text",
            "owner": "xxxx@xxxx.xx",
            "category": "Some Text",
            "description": "Some Text.",
            "template_id": "Some Text",
            "last_update": "2022-11-27T00:11:51.863Z",
            "users": [
                "xxxx@xxxx.xx"
            ]
        }
    }
}"""

    val jsonTest: WorkflowsTest =
        Gson().fromJson(jsonString, WorkflowsTest::class.java)

    println(jsonTest)
}
```

print result works fine :

`WorkflowsTest(values={16694990259825982nLJ=Id(owner=xxxx@xxxx.xx, createdAt=2022-11-26T21:43:45.982Z, lastUpdate=2022-11-27T00:11:51.863Z, name=Some Text, description=Some Text., templateId=Some Text, id=16694990259825982nLJ, category=Some Text, users=[xxxx@xxxx.xx])})`

```
> **UPDATE**

I solved the issue by only changing the Api response data class : 

Old : 

    @Serializable
    data class ApiResponse(
        @Transient
        val success: Boolean? = null,
        val message: String? = null,
        val values: WorkflowsTest? = null,
        val status: Int,
        @Transient
        val error: Exception? = null

to the new one (focus on the values field) : 

    @Serializable
    data class ApiResponse(
        @Transient
        val success: Boolean? = null,
        val message: String? = null,
        val values: Map<String, Id>? = null,
        val status: Int,
        @Transient
        val error: Exception? = null
    )

and magically it works.
```

Comment: You need a custom deserializer. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639018/java-parse-json-with-array-with-different-object-types-gson-or-jackson-or-etc/45640511#45640511) Gson Example

Comment: @AtakanCoşar Thank you for your answer, but that's not needed actually for my case, and I have managed to solve the issue, fortunately.